# Congratulations! You've earned -> User did not earn this badge

Tags: bug, badges

I'm curious to know what happened with my `curious` badge.

I've received a "Congratulations!":

[image]

But once clicked on "[Learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious?userid=1765658)", I read *"F. Hauri ... did not earn this badge."*:

[image]

**???**

#### Because of my *curiosity*: Poll every minutes, waiting for...

Runing this loop:

```
while [[ $(sed -ne '
  /class="user-details/,/^<\/div/{ /^<\/div/{ N;s/^.*>//g;p; } }
  ' < <(
    wget -qO - 'https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious?userid=1765658'
  )) == 'did not earn this badge.'* ]];do sleep 60
done;echo $((EPOCHSECONDS-1656662040))
```

(I've received congratulation `@1656662040`)

The answer was: **`27132`**. Something like 7 hours and 32 minutes later!!

Comment: Maybe it's some caching somewhere...

Comment: @Cerbrus Of course, I've already flushed my cache, But opened [Curious badges for f-hauri](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious?userid=1765658) in another browser, still no badge.  You could try yourself, following this link! Considering ny 1st screenshot, there is something wrong!

Comment: I'm not talking about client-side caching, here.

Comment: Hmmm ... somewhere, on server side, then!? Ok.

Comment: All bugs on this site can be explained by caching. Not all of them will go away if caching would be turned off though.

Comment: Give it a day. Badge batches run in-frequently, some batches only runs once per 24 hours.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to [this answer by animuson on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/286189/what-does-it-mean-when-the-badge-page-says-did-not-earn-this-badge)

> The progress tracker on your profile will tell you immediately when you currently qualify to be awarded a new badge. However, badge awarding is still not instantaneous. You still have to wait for the relevant script's next run before the system will formally award it to you. Until it does get awarded, you know you don't have to do anything else to qualify for it. The badge is on its way.

> The only exception here is tag badges, which can be awarded immediately upon viewing your profile when you currently qualify for the badge, under certain conditions.

A few hours later [you do have the badge now](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious?userid=1765658)

Comment: Ah, the old "under certain conditions," which we're not going to tell you what they are!

Comment: *`A few hours later`*... I've watched for the badge every minutes until I've earned him. He was arrived 7 hours 33 minutes after the congratulation!

Comment: @F.Hauri It probably takes between 6 and 8 hours by design.